# STUFF Not Working in Update SQL Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Running this query on SQL Server 2008 R2

```
update Documents
set Url = STUFF(Url, CHARINDEX('2', Url), 1, '1')
where url != '' and Url is not null
```

gives the error

```
Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Url', table 'dbo.Documents'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE     fails. The statement has been terminated.
```

Note that the select works normally

```
SELECT STUFF(url, CHARINDEX('2', Url), 1, '1')
FROM Documents
where url != ''
```

Comment: check if any url value exists which does not have '2' using `SELECT url
FROM Documents WHERE Url NOT LIKE  '%2%'`

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx):

> If *expressionToFind* is not found within *expressionToSearch*, `CHARINDEX` returns 0.

From the documentation for [`STUFF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx):

> If the start position is 0, a null value is returned

Maybe you want to add:

```
Url like '%2%'
```

as an extra condition<sup>1</sup> in your `WHERE` clause.

---

E.g. look at this example:

```
;With Example as (
    select 'abc' as Url
)
select Url, CHARINDEX('2',Url),STUFF(Url, CHARINDEX('2', Url), 1, '1')
from Example
```

Which produces the result:

```
Url              
---- ----------- -------
abc  0           NULL
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, it could stand alone as the condition for this `UPDATE` since it will, as a by-product, eliminate `Url`s which are `NULL` or empty. But you may prefer to retain the other conditions to make it clear that you wanted to exclude those specific values.

Comment: why is it returning Null or empty rows when I already specified in the where clause that no nulls or '' should be worked, what is the order of execution of this query

Comment: `STUFF` is returning `NULL` because you're supplying a start position of 0 (my second quote). You're supplying a start position of 0 because one of the `Url` values doesn't *contain* the character `2`, and so that's what `CHARINDEX` returns in such as case (my first quote).

Comment: is the where clause not supppose to filter out those empty url rows? The where clause should run first shouldn't it? I observed that the null was as a result of empty rows

Comment: @kolexinfos - they're not **empty**. Say you've got a `Url` value of `I'mAHappyUrlThatDoesn'tContainTheDigitTwo`. It's *that* value that's being transformed into a `NULL` and that's why I suggested adding a filter to the `WHERE` clause so that you only work against `Url`s that *do* contain `2`.

Comment: @kolexinfos - if you want more thorough analysis, you need to put more effort into your question - add scripts to your question that create the table (just the columns needed for the rest of the scripts) and sample data (just a few rows, probably) that *exhibit the problem*.